# Concepts figuratively unable to be pulled apart?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to describe the connection between two 'concepts' *information literacy* and *information technology*.

I want to use a word that emphasises the strength of the bond between them. I want a word that carries a metaphorical sense that trying to pull or tug the bond will be unsuccessful. This pull/tug aspect is important to my context because [please fill this part in].

I've thought about using *inseparable*, or *in-extractable*, but neither of these stress the forceful 'pull' or 'tugging' aspect. I tried searching for synonyms of *inseparable* and *in-extractable*, but the results weren't exactly what I was looking for because [some examples of synonyms that don't work here].

Comment: Why do you need to stress the forceful "pull" or "tugging" aspect? *Inseparable* implies that you cannot separate it by any means. That includes tugging and pulling and chainsawing and driving a semi through it. What is it about tugging that you specifically need to mention it over chainsawing?

Comment: I wonder whether you’re looking for two things’ [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), without which [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_conditions) and other timing matters become problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Inextricable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inextricable) comes to mind

> incapable of being disentangled or untied *an inextricable knot*

Source: Merriam-Webster

@Bib suggests *inextricably bound*

Comment: And the downvote is for???

Answer (score 1):

*bonded,* as in 'family bonds':

ODO on *[bonded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bonded)*

> **1.1** Emotionally or psychologically linked:
>   *a strongly bonded group of females*

See the article on [Human Bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_bonding) on Wikipedia:

> Human bonding is the process of development of a close, interpersonal relationship. It most commonly takes place between family members or friends,[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bonded) but can also develop among groups, such as sporting teams and whenever people spend time together. Bonding is a mutual, interactive process, and is different from simple liking.
>   …

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think a colorful phrase like:

```
difficult to pull apart
```

may be your best bet.

Really, the following sentence

```
Information literacy and information technology are difficult to pull apart.
```

...is a very fine sentence. It's what Churchill would say.

Always try to say **exactly what you mean**.  Forget about fancy words.

That sentence is so good, it would be excellent to begin your article with.

That being said, **inextricably bound** is the everyday, usual phrase here that everyone uses when they want to sound like they are using a fancy word, think they are talking French or whatever.

```
Information literacy and information technology are inextricably bound.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, the aforementioned "two concepts" are information literacy and information technology; I know, not strictly "concepts," but I am thinking conceptually for the purposes of an assignment. I think the word "stickyness" which you mention above is what I had envisioned in my mind when I posted the question. Anyway, I hope that clears things up!